# How can i update tags for a Azure NotificationHub installation via the backend, without an installationId?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I'm using the [Installation approach](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-overview/) to handle my push notifications.

Works great!

However, how can i update tags for an installation via the backend, without knowing the `installationId`?

E.g with *Registrations*, i can do this:

`_hub.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync("member:1")`

To then update all registrations for that user, via my backend.

But how do i do this with installations? There is no equivalent `GetInstallationsByTagAsync`, there is only `GetInstallationAsync`, which needs the `installationId` (which i don't have, since this a backend/background operation).

Answer (score 0):

Notification Hubs does not have a getInstallationByTag method available at this point in time so Installation IDs would be necessary. It is on our roadmap to provide a complete set of registration equivalent support for installations.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's fine, but then how can i solve my problem?

Comment: Seems like this is a pretty big oversight. Essentially there's no way to manage tags via the backend.

Comment: Yeah. We have many customer requests on this and we are hoping to provide such capabilities soon!